# Вырубается бук каждые 20-30 минут (а то и через 10), когда печатаю

Tags: windows, ноутбук

Старый ноут брал в 2011, toshiba satellite c850 - b3k. Начал шуметь вентилятор, у рукодельца поменял на новый, шуметь перестал. Стал вырубаться каждые 20-30 минут. Выключится и на перезагрузку. Что только не делал - проверял работу от батареи только, загрузил доктора веба cureit. Бесполезно.
Но заметил такую вещь - если бук просто включен, играет ютуб - работает нормально (целые сутки без сбоев). Запускал в безопасном режиме - тоже вырубается, когда печатал. Звонил в тошиба - но они уже не поддерживают эту модель.

Подскажите что можно сделать, кроме как переустановить (и то неизвестно, не повторится ли ситуация) .
Паста на проце свежая, качественная. Температура в аиде тоже нормальная показывает. Стоит 2 года windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: А вы уверены что блоку питания хватает мощности крутить ваш новый вентилятор?

Comment: Можно попробовать запустить какой-нибудь бенчмарк. Чтобы отсечь (или подтвердить) версию, что дело в железе. И в какой программе вы печатаете, когда ноутбук перезагружается?

Comment: и в нотпад ++ и в хроме

Comment: а бенчмарк это что?

Comment: Если перезагрузка происходит при наборе текста, то возможно что из за короткого замыкания при нажатии на клавиатуру

Comment: КАК вариант, спасибо

Comment: Перестал шуметь = не крутится?

Comment: Если просто выключается, без синего экрана и ошибки в системном журнале, то это стопудово проблема железа. Процессору напряжения не хватает, перегревается, или что-то в этом роде.